# Would I need to put "a" at the beginning of this sentence?

Tags: sentence, indefinite-articles

I'm writing a statement in which I wanna say something like:

Last semester I taught course xyz. Prerequisite for many upper-level courses, course xyz covers topics such as ...

Would it be better if I started the second sentence with 'A prerequisite"?

Comment: Yes, it needs to be "A prerequisite..."

Comment: No, it doesn't 'need' the article, as _prerequisite_ is an adjective as well as a noun. But this adjective used in an absolute construction would sound incorrect to many and rarefied to others.

Comment: so do you think its better to go ahead and use the article, so that it doesn't sound incorrect and rarefied?

Comment: I wanna say yes.

Comment: I’d write *As a prerequisite...*